# My div is hidden on mobile size by the footer in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: css, prestashop-1.6

as you can see in my website http://sunray.co.il/en/
when tryin to set broswer size to mobile size, you cant see all the "google map" block, hope that you can help me guys, thanks!
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEP9C.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit global.css:8386

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
    #cmsinfo_block {
        min-height: 554px;
        height: 554px;
        padding-left: 13px;
        padding-right: 13px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its work but now the thier is big blank space after facebook block,
but maybe i have fixed it by spilt the the CSS code #faceb.. ,#cmsbloack.. {} 
to:
#facebook {}
#cmsblock {}

The problem is that its took time till i can see the changes, maybe some cache problem, even that I reset it everytime (from backend)

Comment: Yes you can reload caché using Ctrl + F5
Also i see that you opted for two columns design right?